# Android Pay API sample not able to work

Tags: android-studio

I am new to programming. I took the sample from https://github.com/android-pay/androidpay-quickstart, now I am getting this problem when I click "Sign in with Google", [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhCa4.png)

any help please?

Answer (score 0):

You can always sign in with any email address and password.
Make sure you have installed Android Pay app in your phone and registered respective card in it.